# PostgreSQL 11 trigger can't select a value in a table to use it in a second table

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Here's a sample of log :

```
gid alti  numlog
1   79.55 1
2   79.65 2
```

Here's a sample of us :

```
gid numlog numus sommet base alti_sommet alti_base
1   1      1000  0      0.25 (79.55-0)   (79.55-0.25)
2   1      1001  0.25   0.39 (79.55-0.25)(79.55-0.39)
3   1      1002  0.39   0.59 (79.55-0.39) ...
4   2      1000  0      0.15 (79.65-0)
5   2      1001  0.15   0.40 (79.65-0.15)
```

With a trigger on us, I would like to update alti_sommet and alti_base with the result of the math between ().

I create this function just for alti_base for now :

```
create or replace function activite.calcul_alti_us()
returns trigger as
$body$
 BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP IN ('insert')) THEN
  NEW.alti_base = l.alti-NEW.base from log l where NEW.numlog = l.numlog ;
 return NEW ;
  END IF ;
 return NULL ;
END ;
$body$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

and the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_calcul_alti_us
AFTER insert
ON us
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE activite.calcul_alti_us();
```

The result : **alti_surface = 0** everywhere.
I tried :

```
NEW.alti_base = (select l.alti-NEW.base from activite.log l where NEW.numlog =l.numlog) ;
```

I tried with a trigger *BEFORE* as well.
Both failed. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors:

- It must be a `BEFORE` trigger to modify the row about to be inserted.
- There is no column `base` in table `log`.
- `TG_OP` is always in upper case, so you must compare with `'INSERT'`.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger after so I make an update on us instead of using TG_OP. Now it works as expected with this function :

```
create or replace function activite.calcul_alti_us()
returns trigger as
$body$
BEGIN
 update us
 set (alti_base, alti_sommet) = (l.alti - base, l.alti-sommet) 
 from log l 
 where us.numlog = l.numlog ;
 return NEW ;
END ;
$body$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

Comment: The problem is here that, each time on insert in tbl log, the trigger is done on the full tbl us. But I would like the trigger to apply only to the rows inserted in tbl log. I tried `...where NEW.us.numlog = l.numlog` but it failed.